# Convert Dicom Image to JPG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dll, dependencies, rubygems, imagemagick

I am trying to convert a dicom file to JPG which I would then use to show as thumbnail for the dicom file. I am using the code below to convert the dicom file but When I execute it I get the following error

> 'write': no encode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1272 (Magick::ImageMagickError)

I am using ruby version **2.7.0** and I have installed ImageMagick **7.1.0-4** and the supportive gems. How to solve this error?

```
require 'dicom'
require 'rmagick'
include DICOM

dcm = DObject.read("sample.dcm")
image = dcm.image(:frame => 5)
image.normalize.write("test.jpeg");
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you got `include DICOM` from. I can't see anything that implies that the library should be used as a mixin.

Comment: its from this link https://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-on-medicine-converting-dicom-to-jpg/

Comment: I don't really know that much about DICOM but the ruby part of the tutorial is horrible and it's quite old. The author does not know what he's doing. Do not install ruby with apt-get or gems with sudo.

Comment: Sorry, it's a pretty niche task and your best chance  is probably to read though the documentation for the dicom gem and rmagic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reinstall ImageMagick-7.1.0-26 along with libgdcm-tools on my system and the above mentioned code worked fine. So Imagemagick needs these additional libraries (libjpeg62-dev, libtiff-dev, libpng-dev, libpng12-0 and libgdcm-tools) to work with these image types. I don't know if this is correct or not but that the problem I was facing has been resolved by following this approach. Here are some of the links which helped me in solving this

> [Install ImageMagick with JPG TIFF and PNG Delegates](https://gist.github.com/zeeq911/eed64dffbf77e976beef3c362c51342b)
>
> [How to configure and build with libgcdm for lossless jpeg conversion
> and dicom support](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/1413)